# How to make this countdown running in thread and start it when button pressed?

Tags: android, button, android-studio, count, countdown

This code are given by google.I want this code running in background as a Thread and start it when button is clicked.I've tried so many times and it doesn't work .Please help me

```
    new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            box2three.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            box2three.setText("Time's up!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: What is your actual requirement?

Comment: Where does it decrements the elapsed time to reach finish time?